# unable to match regex with text

Tags: node.js, regex

I have this regex for an html

```
var appraisalRx = /function savedAppraisalId\(\)\n\s+\{\n\s+return (\d{8})/;
let res = html.toString().match(appraisalRx);
if (res == null || res.length == 0)
          console.log("No Appraisal ID Found in HTML");
```

And this is the html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function savedAppraisalId()
        {
            return 11457602;
        }
    </script>
```

I test it in online regex checker and it seems to be working fine. But it isnt in here.

Comment: Please remove both `\n`s and re-try.

Comment: That did the trick. But why was it not working with it?

Comment: Your line endings are `\r\n`, CRLF, right? And you only used `\n` in the pattern.

Comment: So I need to use all or none?

Comment: When I test it in VScode it doens't work but during run time it works. Why is that?